# when counting elements in JS - does the counting Objects sort it's keys?

Tags: javascript, hash

I am using the following code to count elements in a string and store them in an Object.

```html
    let count1 = {},
    count2 = {},

    for (n of str1) {
    count1[n] = (count1[n] || 0) + 1;
    }
    for (n of str2) {
    count2[n] = (count2[n] || 0) + 1;
    }
```

the result seems to be an object that sort itself without an explicit sort function (ie key-value pairs are accumulated in a sorted order and not the order in which they were added.)

[image]

is this always the case in JS?

Comment: Might depend on the implementation, but at least in Chrome, numeric keys always come first, sequentially. It's only non-numeric keys that will be listed in insertion order

Comment: ^^ it is the actual standard. symbols are at the end.